# Strange border when inserting image to PDF generated by Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I have an image here at this link: http://i711.photobucket.com/albums/ww116/xuanchienuit/1.png

I am trying to insert this image as background to the pdf using the following method:

```
image_path = "..." #path to the image
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.image image_path, width: pdf.bounds.width, height: pdf.bounds.height

pdf.render_file "test.png"
```

And the output PDF is at this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iZPOjOn1osUzJSUTdDZGROZzQ/view?usp=sharing

The problem is in the PDF, you can see a gray border on top and bottom of the image (if you don't see the border, try zooming in/out and you would see the border).

What is going on here? I think there could be something wrong with the image but I am not sure. I hope you guys will have a better thought.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting height and width, try setting the position, and letting the image scale to best fit the available space (match height, match width, match both)? You might -- all conjecture here -- be seeing some artifact of the image getting stretched to the pdf region (if the image dimensions don't match the pdf precisely).

```
pdf.image image_path,
          :position => :center,
          :vposition => :center,
          :fit => [pdf.bounds.width, pdf.bounds.height]
```